# WPF DataGridCell Styling - Binding for Tooltips on multiple columns

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding, tooltip

I have a DataGrid that has an unknown number of columns. From the screenshot you will see there are 3 EF columns:

[image]

What you cannot see is that each EF column has other columns that are hidden that holds other information about its respective EF column. For example, There is a hidden column before EF1 called 1Status (which is used to conditionally format the cell backgrounds based on its value), and another hidden column named 1AssMeth) which holds the text to appear in the tooltip. Ergo - For each **EF[X]** column there are the respective **XStatus** & **XAssMeth**.

As you can see, I have the conditional background colours working.

The background colors are  handled using a ValueConverter and are implemented with the following Resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <local:PercVerifiedConverter x:Key="PercVerifiedConverter" />
        <Style x:Key="PercVerified" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" >
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource PercVerifiedConverter}}" Value="Red">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush>
                                <GradientStop Color="DarkRed" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource PercVerifiedConverter}}" Value="Green">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush>
                                <GradientStop Color="DarkGreen" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource PercVerifiedConverter}}" Value="Orange">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush>
                                <GradientStop Color="DarkOrange" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

So this all works as far as the background color works... However I wish to also add a Tooltip to the style to return the value in the respective XAssMeth column. So, to get things rolling I did this to the Style above...

```
        <local:PercVerifiedConverter x:Key="PercVerifiedConverter" />
        <Style x:Key="PercVerified" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" >

            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding 1AssMeth}" />

            <Style.Triggers> .....
```

Which as you might imagine returns a Tooltip as expected, but every column has the same tooltip - the value in the **1AssMeth** column.

Hover over the first row in EF[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLo8A.png) and this tooltip appears
[image]

Then hover over the first row of any subsequent columns and the same tooltip text appears.

[image]

I would expect this behavior so am happy about that. What I need to know is how I might go about applying additional binding to the EF[X] columns so I get the correct Tooltip Text from the corresponding XAssMeth column - without loosing the functionality of my Background colour styling.

I can supply more information on the converter or anything else if that might help - but i'm hoping it is something simple? i.e. do I need another converter to get the correct corresponding Column Header XAssMeth or anything like that? If so then an example would be amazing!

P.s. I will be looking to expand on the Tooltip to make something customized - so if anyone is able to throw that into the mix as well, would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with a converter, like the DataTriggers are using:

```
<local:PercVerifiedConverter x:Key="PercVerifiedConverter" />
<local:TooltipConverter x:Key="TooltipConverter" />
<Style x:Key="PercVerified" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" >

        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource TooltipConverter}}" />

    <Style.Triggers>...
```

The VB for the the converter:

```
Public Class TooltipConverter
    Implements IValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
        Convert = Nothing
        Dim cell As DataGridCell
        Dim dc As System.Data.DataRowView

        ' Get the DataGridCell passed in
        cell = TryCast(value, DataGridCell)
        If IsNothing(cell) Then Exit Function

        ' Get the cell's DataContext as our data class
        dc = TryCast(cell.DataContext, System.Data.DataRowView)
        If IsNothing(dc) Then Exit Function

        ' Get the cell's column - need it for the binding
        Dim tc As DataGridTextColumn ' Assuming your cells are DataGridTextColumns
        tc = TryCast(cell.Column, DataGridTextColumn)
        If IsNothing(tc) Then Exit Function

        ' Get the column's binding
        Dim b As Binding
        b = TryCast(tc.Binding, System.Windows.Data.Binding)
        If IsNothing(b) Then Exit Function

        ' Get the path off the binding
        Dim path As String
        path = b.Path.Path ' Name of the property this column is bound to - 1AssMeth, EF1, etc...

        ' If one of the "EF" properties, convert path to the appropriate "AssMeth" path
        If path.Contains("EF") Then
            Dim pvNum = path.Replace("EF", String.Empty) ' EF1 becomes 1
            path = pvNum + "AssMeth" ' path is now 1AssMeth
        End If
        If path.Contains("AssMeth") Then
            Convert = dc(path)
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function
End Class
```

EDIT:
To customize the tooltip, update your style to something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="PercVerified" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" >
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ToolTip}" TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border Background="Beige" BorderBrush="Navy" BorderThickness="2">
                            <StackPanel Width="400" Height="200">
                                <TextBlock Background="Bisque" Foreground="Maroon" Text="ToolTip Header" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                                <TextBlock Text="My tooltip text is:" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}" Background="DarkBlue" Foreground="White" Margin="25" />
                                <TextBlock Text="Something else could go here." />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource TooltipConverter}}" />
    </Style.Setters>
    <Style.Triggers>...
```

Comment: Thanks again J.H!! It all reads about right... However I am getting an error when applying the Style to the cells in the Codebehind: "Additional information: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.' Line number '19' and line position '44'." This Line/position is where the Value is set in the XAML Setter...?! Any ideas?

Comment: I have but a break point in on the top line of the new converter as well and it doesnt seem to get there... I have also re-built?!

Comment: Make sure the tooltipconverter is defined in the XAML before the reference to it -- before the style. Order is important.

Comment: Ignore that - I went and replaced all instances of the string "ToolTipConverter" in the converter and it seems to be working... I may have typed one in and im guessing the XAML is case sensitive??

Comment: Would I be going out on a limb to ask about styling a tooltip that is setup in this way...? ;)

Comment: Not sure what you are asking me. Tooltip setup in what way?

Comment: Im sorry, please bear with me... WPF/XAML is still all quite new to me. Basically I want to be able to apply styling like Bold, and background color to the Tooltips - instead of the standard grey box. I have seen this is easily achievable (for example: https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2013/03/08/wpf-tooltip-control-tips-tricks/ )

Comment: I have been having a play around and cannot see how I can apply this level of styling to the ToolTips when they are declared within a Setter as we have done?

Comment: I updated the answer with the style changes. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it is helpful.

Comment: Amazing...!! Simply amazing! Thank you so much... AGAIN!